# What should be the following tag to a span nested within an anchor?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to learn fundamentals of html and markings.

I want to create an anchor which containes two lines of information.

first line: the name of the link
second line: short explanation

e.g.

```
<a href='#'>
<span>Studies</span>
<span class="alt">-Information about studies</span>
</a>
```

Is this correct?

How should the following (2nd span) be modified if necessary?

Thank you

PS. Both lines need to be surrounded with span for css-styling.

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to HTML5.

Comment: @j08691 Instead of just complaining about the mistake, try to explain why this isn't **HTML5**-specific to the asker, who's obviously not very experienced in web-page design and HTML.

Comment: More correct syntax it will be without first span - you could use `a` style to style that text in `span` and style your second `span` to be in second line and look some doferent

Comment: @Abody97 - Exactly how is my comment a complaint to you? I also find it odd how someone with ~300 rep is telling me how to use this site.

Comment: @j08691 Arguing about the usefulness of your comment is by no means intended to be a personal insult; I'm sorry if you considered it to be one. As for reputation, I don't think that having 16,000+ rep means that anybody with less reputation isn't allowed to address a comment you made. But still, I assure you that my intentions were perfectly healthy.

Comment: j0 something; it's a complaint to everyone. You suck. Questions here belong to us all, we believe. And this is relative to html5 because I ask about tags. There's loads new with html5. Why else would I tag the question as html5?

Comment: @Phil - I have no idea, and obviously neither did anyone else which is why the tag was pulled.

Comment: j0 something; I thought that putting that tag would cast it specified as an html5 question. I'm a moron, I suck then. Thank you for the complaint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't rule out using a `br` tag. This is a semantically-appropriate place for a `br` tag (forcing a hard break inside a line or paragraph of text). Plus, if you use a `br` tag, it may no longer be necessary to put either of the two lines of text in separate tags, unless you want to style them differently.

```
<a href='#'>
    Studies<br/>
    -Information about studies
</a>
```

Second, try viewing the HTML with stylesheets disabled (I do this in Firefox by pressing ctrl-shift-S, with a little help from the Web Developer extension). Is the browser able to render the content in an easy-to-read way based solely on the HTML provided? To some extent, the more readable the "unstyled" content appears, the more semantically-correct the HTML is.

Given that the second line of text seems to be secondary to the first line (a subtitle, not as important, possibly redundant or not entirely essential), putting the first line in a `strong` tag or putting the second line in a `small` tag are a couple ways to establish the relative importance of the two lines, if you wish to do so.

```
<a href='#'>
    <strong>Studies</strong><br/>
    -Information about studies
</a>

<a href='#'>
    Studies<br/>
    <small>-Information about studies</small>
</a>
```

There's some room for personal preference here. These are just two approaches.

It may be a little bit of a stretch using a `small` tag in a case like this, but it's not entirely inappropriate. A `small` tag is typically used for "fine print", attribution, disclaimers, or side comments. It doesn't semantically mean the text is small, but it does tend to be used for content that's secondary to something else (that clarifies something else). It should though only be used for text that's short in length.

And a `strong` tag doesn't have to be styled bold. In fact, that's the whole point of semantic markup: It doesn't specify or imply how the content will be styled; all it does is offer a hint to the meaning or context of the content. A `strong` tag can reasonably be given a style of `font-weight:normal`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that those are in separate lines, try using the `<div>` tag instead. You can still specify a class for styling, the only difference is that `<div>`s are block-elements; each of them is rendered on a separate line. Here's the modified version of your code:

```
<a href='#'>
Studies
<div class="alt">-Information about studies</div>
</a>
```

Another, slightly more preferable way of doing that is by styling the elements to be block-elements. That can be used by setting the CSS [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property to `block`. Something like:

```
<a href='#'>
Studies
<span class = "alt block">-Information about studies</span>
</a>
```

(Note that `class = "alt block"` means the element has both classes `alt` and `block`, and note also that the first `<span>` is removed because there's no need to style that node with anything).

CSS:

```
.block {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope that helped you!

Comment: @Tamlyn So basically you're saying that one should use `<span>` and style it with `display: block;` instead of just using `<div>`? I might be missing something here, but what's the point?

Comment: Agree with Tamlyn, the markup you've provided is valid only with html5 doctype (in all other cases you'll have validation errors)

Comment: But he should definitely use `display:block` for the anchor tag, if he were to use `<div>s`

Comment: @Abody97, that is a crusial point imo, because you need to understand that html is for markup, not for styles. So chosing a `div` becaue you need it _look like_ block - is a bad idea ;)

Comment: @snuffn div has default `display: block` in ALL browser, so you dont need to add it in css

Comment: @skip405 The default CSS for `<div>` elements in all major browsers includes that they're block-level elements (i.e., `display: block` is one of the rules in the default CSS). I don't see why it actually matters, but I appreciate the point. I'll update the answer to be more thorough about that.

Comment: I said the anchor tag. It should be `<a href="" style="display:block;"><div>...</div></a>`.

Comment: @snuffn Uh.. My bad, but anyway the proper markup should be: `<a> Studies <span> - More info</span></a>`

Comment: No worries. :) And yes, I agree.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, Abody97. I don't agree with any of the three variants you provided.

Comment: @Tamlyn updated the answer to take your points in consideration. Thanks a lot for pointing out these good-practices.

Comment: @skip405 In the good spirit of collaboratively-built-and-improved Q&A sites, I should thank you for the downvote :) To some level, anyway :P

Comment: @Abody97 You shouldn't use <br> only for split link into 2 lines. Try to write HTML focusing on content. And then add CSS for look, and JS for interactions.